# PTIJ : Why did Obi-Wan Kenobi think Jedi of HaForce strengthen after מָוֶת?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

PTIJ: **Why did Obi-Wan Kenobi think Jedi of HaForce strengthen after מָוֶת?**

> “If you strike me down, I shall become more powerful than you can possibly imagine.”

**Similar to אֱלִישָׁ֔ע Elisha in 2 Kings 13:21**

Ein Yaakov (Glick Edition), Chullin 1:3 (Fol. 7):

> “If the righteous are so great while alive how much the more are they great after their death; for R. Chama b. Chanina said: 'The righteous are great after their death even more so than during their lives, as it is said (II Kings 13, 21) And it came to pass as they were burying a man, that, behold, they saw the band; and they cast down the man into the sepulchre of Elisha; and as the man came and touched the bones of Elisha, he revived, and rose up on his feet.' " R. Papa then said to Abaye: "Perhaps this happened in order to fulfill the blessing of Elijah, as it is written (Ib. 2, 9) I pray the, let a double portion of thy spirit be upon me?"

[https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.13.21?lang=bi&with=Ein%20Yaakov%20(Glick%20Edition)&lang2=en]

**This question is Purim Torah and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. [See the Purim Torah policy: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated].**

Comment: Because Obi-Wan Kenobi was a *maamin*?

Answer (score 1):

B"H

The shoyresh of the word "Jedi" in the original Lawshoyn Hawkoydish is actuall potentially "yehdee", like the monster, or yoodee, or yehoodee, meaning one from the nation of Yisroyayl, who are called yihoodeem after the self sacrifice of yehudah, the force is the koyaych hawpoyl shebinifil, which also exists in each of the yehoodeem...